# lseek giving ESPIPE error

Tags: c, file, lseek

I have a normal file opened, it acts as a database of records. I opened it as:

```
fd = open ("file", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0644);
```

Then in my `find_record` function,  I move the offset to the beginning.

```
ret_val = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Its throwing an `ESPIPE` error. Right now I don't know what's happening.
Is my file descriptor treated as a pipe? if yes, Why?

Is `lseek` actually working ? Its should be beacuse the `ret_val` is not -1.

Comment: did you check for the success of `open()`?

Comment: Yes, it has no issues. I wrote and read records into the "file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `errno`will be reset on a successful call.

You should only check the value of `errno` if the return value indicates an error.

Comment: Oh. shouldn't the default value for `errno` be 0

Comment: `ESPIPE` is actually `errno` 29

Comment: The spec says that it will be set by any call that results in an error (for all calls that use errno). Other than that it can have any value.

Comment: I've seen code where errno was explicitly set to zero before a system call and then checked afterwards.  For most system calls there's some sentinel value indicating an error ... but some apparently have no way other than errno to do this.